# How can i print arabic in Bixion 350III using OPOS in C#

Tags: c#, forms, opos

The code for button click for arabic printing

```
 private void btnPrintArabic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

//Just For Display in List
        AddList("+Print Arabic");


        var source = "على";

        var westernLatin = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
        var arabic = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);

        var bytes = arabic.GetBytes(source);
        var result = westernLatin.GetString(bytes); // Uáì
        Printer.MapCharacterSet = true;
        Printer.CharacterSet = 864;

        int nRC = Printer.PrintNormal(2, result);
        AddList("Print Arabic = " + nRC);
        AddList("-Print Arabic " + ((nRC == (int)OPOS_Constants.OPOS_SUCCESS) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed"));
    }
```

Is there any mistake in what iam doing.I tried for the result for long but even in stack there was no proper answer.Printer opening and closing and normal printing is working fine.Its not working when it comes to other languages

I tried several references but was not able to print arabic

[Other Option By Khalid](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8798e161-46fe-477c-8927-9dd659b8ea40/escpos-arabic-letters-is-separated?forum=posfordotnet)

Reference for Other Result

[Other Option By Khalid](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8798e161-46fe-477c-8927-9dd659b8ea40/escpos-arabic-letters-is-separated?forum=posfordotnet)

Reference for Opos Manual For Bixilon

http://bixolon.com/upload/download/manual_bxl%20sdk%20for%20ios_upos%20compliant%20api%20reference%20guide_english_rev_1_03.pdf

Comment: Isn't Western Latin encoding 1252?

Comment: sorry its 1256...Its also not working with 1256